# SSRS Group Total with multiple datasets lookups

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools, visual-studio-2022

I have a report with multiple datasets. I am trying to get the total of each expression for each manager. The expressions are lookups. I cannot merge the datasets into one and I cannot reduce the number of columns due to business requirements.

`=Lookup(Fields!EmpId.Value, Fields!EmpId.Value, Fields!TOA.Value,"dsToa")`

I  have  tried `=Sum(Fields!Goal.Value, "dsToa")` which gives the whole total but not the total per manager.  When  I try `=Sum(Fields!Goal.Value, "ManagerName")` I get an error "Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope".

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: design view of report]

[image: grouping details of report]

[image: error when trying to sum by group]

Comment: what happens if you wrap a sum around the lookup for yorr Totals? Same expression as the look up? = sum(Lookup(Fields!EmpId.Value, Fields!EmpId.Value, Fields!TOA.Value,"dsToa"))